# how to send data from websocket server to client continuously

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, sockets, websocket

My aim is to write a code to ping through multiple IP address and sends its result to the websocket in a continuous manner

I have this code to send ping data to client using websocket, but it waits for a message from client to be received in other to check check the ping agian.
How can I do this code to continuously send ping data to the client and not wait for client to send a message

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed
import subprocess
from platform import system
import asyncio
import websockets

ip_addresses = [
    '81.168.1.228', 
    '4.2.2.4', 
    '10.10.20.25', 
    '8.8.8.8', 
    '192.168.1.1', 
    '192.168.10.123',
    '10.10.10.1'
]

connected = set()

def check_connection(ip_address):
    try:
        output = subprocess.check_output("ping -{} 1 {}".format('n' if system().lower(
        ) == "windows" else 'c', ip_address), shell=True, universal_newlines=True)
        if ('timeout' in output) or ('unreachable' in output):
            return {'ip_address': ip_address, 'status': 'Down'}
        else:
            return {'ip_address': ip_address, 'status': 'Up'}
    except Exception:
        return {'ip_address': ip_address, 'status': 'Down'}


async def main(websocket, path):
    connected.add(websocket)
    try:
        async for message in websocket:
            with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
                result = [executor.submit(check_connection, ip) for ip in ip_addresses]
                for f in as_completed(result):
                    print(f.result())
                    await websocket.send(f.result())
    finally:
        connected.remove(websocket)

start_server = websockets.serve(main, 'localhost', 7788)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(start_server)
loop.run_forever()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a tcp socket is not what you looking for - alternatives:

1. Try out a udp. This protocol send data without checking if data received by client
2. Setup webserver on client and send the data per post or get

That was my idea.